# hibernate 5 - custom sequences - mariaDB 11

Tags: hibernate, mariadb, sequence

When hibernate try to run this query to get the next Value from sequence

Query :- Query is: select next_val as id_val from my_sequence_table for update

I got this exception :-
**Caused by:

java.sql.SQLException: Unknown column 'next_val' in 'field list'**

while saving new entity with generation type = sequence
iam double sure that sequence is exist in DB

I think this is hibernate issue as the next_val word in the query should be replaced with another true column name

the exception is fired on on the generator method of SequenceStyleGenerator class

```
  @Override
    public Serializable generate(final SharedSessionContractImplementor session, final Object object) throws HibernateException {
        TaxClaimReference claimReference = (TaxClaimReference) object;
        valuePrefix = claimReference.getRegisterReferencePrefix();
        return valuePrefix + String.format(numberFormat, super.generate(session, object));
    }
```

Comment: Is this the same as [CONJ-1076](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJ-1076)?

Comment: yes iam using mariaDB 11 , i think so it is the same @danblack